# Angular no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" with Karma testing

Tags: angular, karma-runner

I am trying to test a form with Karma, but the following error occured:

`'Failed: Template parse errors: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm"'.`

This form works fine when I run it outside of Karma. The code for the form looks like this:

```html
<div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="10px">
    <form novalidate [formGroup]="loginForm" #lForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <mat-form-field class="full-width">
        <input matInput formControlName="userName" placeholder="User Name" type="text">
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field class="full-width">
        <input matInput formControlName="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
      </mat-form-field>
      <button
        type="submit"
        mat-button
        class="primary-button"
      >
        Login
      </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

And the spec.ts file looks like this:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        FlexLayoutModule
      ],
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Everything I can find about this error says that importing the FormsModule will fix the error, but I have already done this, so I'm not sure what else to do. I'm using **Angular 7** and **Karma 3**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `[formGroup]` on your form.

So you're creating a reactive form.

So you need to import `ReactiveFormsModule`, not `FormsModule`. See [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

Also, you're defining an `lForm` variable, but you're not using it. And you're setting `novalidate` for nothing, since Angular forms do that for you.

Comment: This is my first time trying Angular and I was following a tutorial that showed the form the way I had it. I made the changes you suggested and that fixed things. Thanks for your help.